# UIView animateWithDuration not animating when duration changes

Tags: iphone, ios, animation

I have a method named

```
- (void) startAnimationForTime : (NSNumber* ) time {
```

which I call from some other place in my code. It works well for the first time I call the method, but when I call it with some other time duration it still animates with previous time duration. Animation speed does not change.
Suppose I call my method like this for the first time...

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startAnimationForTime:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:20.0] waitUntilDone:NO];
```

And if I call it from some other place as,

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startAnimationForTime:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.0] waitUntilDone:NO];
```

the animation speed is expected to change, but it doesn't.
I'm posting my animation method here...

In some other method in my code,

```
  animator1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"beach_bg.png"]];
  animator2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"beach_bg.png"]];

  animator1.frame = CGRectMake(0,-bgHeight,320,bgHeight);
  animator2.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,bgHeight);



- (void) startAnimationForTime : (NSNumber*) time {

    animator1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"beach_bg.png"]];
    animator2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"beach_bg.png"]];

    [self.view addSubview:animator1];
    [self.view addSubview:animator2];
    [self.view addSubview:playTime];
    [self.view addSubview:pauseButton];
    [self.view addSubview:bgImageView];

    animator1.frame = CGRectMake(0,-bgHeight,320,bgHeight);
    animator2.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,bgHeight);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[time floatValue]
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         animator2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, bgHeight);  }
                     completion:^(BOOL fin) { if (fin){}}];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[time floatValue]
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         animator1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, bgHeight);  }
                     completion:^(BOOL fin) { if (fin){}}];

}
```

I also tried this for the second time I call the method,

```
animator1.frame = [[animator1.layer presentationLayer]frame];

animator2.frame = [[animator2.layer presentationLayer]frame];
```

This will get me current frame of my `animator1` and `animator2`. But that doesn't work either.
I'm badly stuck at this..

Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I can't see any mistake in your code, did you try to put some loggin / breakpoint in "startAnimationForTime" and check what's the time you get there, I think that's a good point to start the debugging from.

Comment: yes i did put a NSLog statement.  it gives me the correct duration.

Comment: And it's only called once? If you would call it once with 20, and directly after that with 10 seconds, I think it may ignore the 2nd call, if it arrives during animation of the 1st call.
Otherwise I'm afraid I can't really help you with that. When the time is correct in [UIView animateWithDuration...], it should be working ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please put this code before

```
 animator1.frame = CGRectMake(0,-bgHeight,320,bgHeight);
    animator2.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,bgHeight);
```

This

```
[self.view addSubview:animator1];
    [self.view addSubview:animator2];
    [self.view addSubview:playTime];
    [self.view addSubview:pauseButton];
    [self.view addSubview:bgImageView];
```

and try to animate. Hope this helps